# Is there an easy way to create a model with multiple texture inputs and then easily switch between them?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I created a model in blender and wrapped it with two custom images, I want to be able to toggle between each wrap. Is there an easy way to have two inputs for the wraps and then turn one off/on?
I used uv mapping in order to wrap the model.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can plug both into a Mix RGB node - and then toggle between 0 or 1.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Object Properties* tab add a custom property:

[image]

Right-click its value and choose *Copy As New Driver*:

[image]

Go to your shader and put a *Mix RGB* node as a switch between the two textures, right-click its *Factor* input and choose *Paste Driver*:

[image]

In *3D Viewport* select your object (in *Object Mode*), press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *Numbers panel*, expand *Properties* section and change the property.

[image]

Comment: If I want to export the model to three.js or another 3d rendering engine for my website, will I be able to toggle between the two wraps? Or do I need to do something special when exporting? Thank you for the awesome step-by-step for my last question! That was super helpful :)

Comment: I found this article that seems helpful https://medium.com/@matthewmain/how-to-import-a-3d-blender-object-into-a-three-js-project-as-a-gltf-file-5a67290f65f2

Comment: I think GLTF format is limited to a single texture as base color. This problem seems to be more relevant to the framework you're using and people with expertise in three.js might have a solution ready for swapping a material or a single node (texture) in the node setup generated by the GLTF importer of three.js.

Comment: If this was "super helpful", please consider to accept the answer @JuliaKaiser https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, thanks.