# How to switch between multiple textures in a material using a driver

Tags: materials, node-editor, drivers, shader-nodes

I have a customizable model with multiple textures for the body (4 to be exact). How would I be able to easily switch between these textures with a driver. If I had 2 I'd be able to use a mix modifier and add a driver to the factor slider, but since it only has two inputs I don't know how I could do that.

For more specifity, I want to achieve what is answered in this question, but with more than two inputs: [Is there an easy way to create a model with multiple texture inputs and then easily switch between them?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-model-with-multiple-texture-inputs-and-then-eas/213819#213819)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom property, min=0, max=3

use these drivers for the mix factors:

first driver:

[image]

second driver: like first, but scripted expression is "prop - 1"

third driver: "prop - 2"

material:

[image]

result:

[image]

if you wanna do it more carefully you can also use

```
max(prop - 1,0)
```